# How can I shut down an unlisted php-fpm?

Tags: launchd, php

I have two installations of php on my machine.
One came with apache and is a 5.3 version, and I'm trying to use a 5.4 version with nginx.
I'd like to work on project using nginx, but I can't figure out how to turn off apache's pfp-fpm service: it doesn't show up when I use the `sudo launchctl list` command. However, I can see it in the process list, and it claims its parent process is launchd.

When I open the nginx project main page, and call `phpinfo()` on it, the php version displayed is 5.3, this is why I think I failed to launch the correct service. What can I try?

Answer (score 1):

You can just let the apache version alone and set up nginx to proxy to the php-fpm process you want via socket or just another different port. Keep in mind that the default port for php-fpm is 9000 in the case it has the original setup which is using the port and not the socket.